# How to get the object created by bpy.ops.object.duplicate()?

Tags: python

How can I get a reference to the object created by `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()`? It seems that `bpy.context.object` used to have it, but not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

`bpy.ops.object.duplicate()` finishes with the duplicated object as the currently selected object. Therefore, `bpy.context.object` is the reference to the new object.

Ex (assume object selected in 3d viewport):

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()

dupli_obj = bpy.context.object
print(dupli_obj.name)             #check the console
```

If you run this code, does it not give you what you expect?

Comment: I tried your script in a brand new file. It returned the original Cube, not Cube.001 that was created. I know it's weird, but that's what happens, at least in v2.81.16.

Comment: That's what I'm running as well and it behaves just as I explained. No idea why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Works for me too 2.83.2. Worth mentioning it will dupe all selected objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try `bpy.context.active_object`, works for me else try `bpy.context.selected_objects[0]`